# Proper way to validate a HTTPS certificate in a REST .NET client?

Tags: rest, https, ssl-certificate

When you develop a REST API client that talks over HTTPS you should validate that the certificate is the correct one to prevent man-in-the-middle attacks.

The question is how to properly do this validation? (Ie validate the certificate chain?)

Google is mentioning some validation anti-patterns here in a blog post titled [Changes to our SSL Certificates](http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.se/2013/05/changes-to-our-ssl-certificates.html) including:

- Matching the leaf certificate exactly (e.g. by hashing it)
- Matching any other certificate (e.g. Root or Intermediate signing certificate) exactly
- Hard-coding the expected Root certificate,

Answer (score 0):

.NET provides built-in validation mechanisms when you connect to HTTPS resource. You can perform validation yourself as well, but proper validation is a complicated task that involves both local cryptographic operations and use of OCSP servers and CRLs. So I would suggest you to stay with default .NET validation unless you need something custom.

Comment: When a .NET client connects to a HTTPS server, it will do the proper HTTPS certificate chain validation and I as a developer does not need to do any manual step to approve this? I mean it's easy to fake a certificate with Fiddler to make Windows to accept it, so my idea is to actually do some check in my app to verify that I am not seeing any fiddler self-seigned temporary cert.

Comment: @user316 "I mean it's easy to fake a certificate with Fiddler to make Windows to accept it" - this is what human operator does intentionally. Don't do it and you will be safe.